# Align center Circles CSS (number of circles are handled by AngularJS)

Tags: angularjs, css, alignment, center

Below how it looks :

[image]

Below What I would like to have :

[image]

or if getNumber return more for example

[image]
(so basicaly the circle are always align center whatever number my getNumber return)

Below the AngularJS code :

```
<div class="w3-container">
<span ng-repeat="i in getNumber(data.numberOfState) track by $index"  style="margin-right:10%;">     
            <div id="advanced" class="circle" ></div>
 </span>
        <div id="barre"></div>
</div>
```

Below the CSS code :

```
.circle {
border-radius: 50%;
width: 18px;
height: 18px; 
background: RoyalBlue;
display: inline-block;
}

#barre{
width: 100%;
height: 3px;
background: RoyalBlue;
margin-top: -17px;
}

#advanced {
width: 18px;
height: 18px;
 /* TODO */
}

.circleActive {
border-radius: 40%;
width: 15px;
height: 15px; 
background: RoyalBlue;
display: inline-block;
}
```

How to align center the circle on the bar ?

```
right: 50%;
left: 50%;
position: absolute;
```

With this it works but since my circle are iterate by my javascript there are showing at the same coordinated, so I can see only one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `text-align:center;` to `.circle` parent

```
.w3-container {text-align:center;}
```

Here's small snippet for you

```css
.parent {text-align:center;}
.child {height:14px; width:14px; background:royalblue; display:inline-block;}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <span class="child"></span>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <span class="child"></span>
  <span class="child"></span>
  <span class="child"></span>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <span class="child"></span>
  <span class="child"></span>
  <span class="child"></span>
  <span class="child"></span>
  <span class="child"></span>
  <span class="child"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Marcin, I was sure I tried this before but nevermind, it works !

Answer (score 2):

This is easy if you are using a `flexbox` - you only need to give:

```
  display:flex;
  width:100%;
  justify-content: space-around;
```

Some suggestions though:

1. Using `id` inside an `ng-repeat` is wrong, as you will then get multiple `id`s which is invalid.
2. `barre` is omitted and using an `after` psuedo element just for more markup readability.
3. The line (using `after`) is absolutely positioned with respect to the `flexbox`

See demo below:

```css
.circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  background: RoyalBlue;
  display: inline-block;
}
.wrapper {
  display:flex;
  width:100%;
  justify-content: space-around;
  position:relative;
}
.wrapper:after {
  position:absolute;
  content:'';
  display:block;
  width: 100%;
  top:7px;
  height: 3px;
  background: RoyalBlue;
}
.advanced {
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
}
.circleActive {
  border-radius: 40%;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background: RoyalBlue;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="w3-container">
  <div class="wrapper">     
    <div class="circle advanced" ></div>
    <div class="circle advanced circleActive" ></div>
    <div class="circle advanced" ></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Centered, not space-around.

Comment: @kukkuz Thanks for the suggestion, You're right, used id is dirty I didn't realized about the multiple id, I used marcin answer for the moment because I had to add just a line, but I'm going to use this way when I have more time

Answer (score 2):

You can use `display: flex;` for container. To center elements add `justify-content: center;`.

```css
.line {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 50px;
  border-top: 2px solid blue;
}

.circle {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 0 20px;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="line">
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>

<div class="line">
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>

<div class="line">
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```